# Identify ractive js partial in static html

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I am working on a template builder using ractive js and partials. Once the user finishes building the template he can save it. At this point the HTML code gets saved to the database.

The issue appears when he wants to edit it as everything got saved as plain html so we don't have any mustaches so we cannot bind it anymore.

If I know which template was applied initially, can we bind the template to a specific ractive so we can update the mustaches?

An example could be the background-color of a certain div element

---

Update: 26-06: Some more details on the workflow: the user drag and drops elements similar to mailchimp. I have some variables that are replaced - like the name, phone number, listing details etc.

I save the generated html in the database, but I think it would be better to serialize all replaced data and when they want to edit what they built, I load each partial and apply the saved data to each template.

---

Thank you

Comment: Not following your workflow, why don't you just save the template. Can you provide example or more detail?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added some details to it. I think I might have found an alternative for this.

Comment: @VladB maybe this project can give some inspiration :) https://github.com/codler/Build-your-site/tree/gh-pages

Comment: Ah - great stuff. Thank you. Indeed, it seems generating json strings when saving instead saving the full html is the best solution for later edits.